# onclick() Delete JQuery UI tabs cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

I'm using JQuery UI tabs with cookie like this.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs({cookie: { expires: 30}  });
  });

  <a href="#" class="delete-cookie" >Delete Coockie</a>
```

I want to know how can I set cookie to **null / delete** using onclick event.

Thanks.

Comment: this must help http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cookie

Comment: look for if ( o.cookie ) { this._cookie( null, o.cookie ); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.delete-cookie').click ( function () {
            jQuery('#tabs').tabs({cookie: {} });
    });

})
```

or try this

```
jQuery( ".delete-cookie" ).tabs( "click", "cookie", { expires: 30 } );
```